# Issue with tight_layout with matplotlib and cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I recently switched to Matplotlib 3.3.1 and my old script start to complain. I guess it is an issue with cartopy. Here is a minimum reproducible example

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs    
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2,
                       subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()),
                      figsize=[12,7], sharex=True, sharey=True)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Here I copy the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 4, in 
> plt.tight_layout()
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 451, in wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
> line 1490, in tight_layout
> gcf().tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py",
> line 411, in wrapper
> return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py",
> line 2613, in tight_layout
> kwargs = get_tight_layout_figure(
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py",
> line 303, in get_tight_layout_figure
> kwargs = auto_adjust_subplotpars(fig, renderer,
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tight_layout.py",
> line 84, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
> bb += [ax.get_tightbbox(renderer, for_layout_only=True)]
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes_base.py",
> line 4203, in get_tightbbox
> bbox = a.get_tightbbox(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
> line 278, in get_tightbbox
> bbox = self.get_window_extent(renderer)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\patches.py",
> line 598, in get_window_extent
> return self.get_path().get_extents(self.get_transform())
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line
> 603, in get_extents
> return Bbox([xys.min(axis=0), xys.max(axis=0)])
>
> File
> "C:\Users\Vinod\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core_methods.py",
> line 43, in _amin
> return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
>
> ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has
> no identity

Comment: *Any suggestion to fix this issue?* should you include the issue in the post?

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question to also include error message

Comment: Maybe related to: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1207.

Try making a call to `fig.canvas.draw()` before your call to `plt.tight_layout()`.

Comment: Great! fig.canvas.draw() solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a known issue and was addressed in: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/1207. (Making sure you have the latest version of cartopy may resolve this issue).

In the meanwhile, as a workaround it was noted that you could make a call to `fig.canvas.draw()` before your call to `plt.tight_layout()`.